# Accessing iframe with jquery from parent window on two different ports

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe of localhost:9001 inside localhost:9000, because these are considered different domains I can't impact the iframe from the parent. Is there a way around this given that I own and can change both port's code?

I've researched and know of the postMessage option, is that the only thing I can do?

The error I get is "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9000" from accessing a cross-origin frame"